# How to take user voice input in applescript

Tags: applescript

I want to be able to take in input from the user in a program and have them speak it instead of type it into a text box. Is there any way to do this?

Any help would be appreciated.....

Comment: Yes, you can enable **dictation** in macOS, typically by double tapping the **`fn`** key in any input field.

Comment: @CJK  i am already doing that, my question is how to do it in an applescript program. Sorry if I wasn't clear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you change the shortcut used to **start dictation** (*System Preferences > Keyboard > Dictation > Shortcut*) to either `Press Left Command Key Twice` or `Press Either Command Key Twice`, you can trigger this shortcut using *System Events* (provided the necessary [accessibility privileges](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/MacAutomationScriptingGuide/AutomatetheUserInterface.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016239-CH69-SW1) are granted):

```
    delay 0.1
    tell application "System Events" to repeat 2 times
        key down command
        key up command
    end repeat
```

Alternatively, you can trigger the menu item:

```
    tell application "System Events" to tell ¬
        (the first process whose frontmost is true) to tell ¬
        menu bar 1 to tell ¬
        menu bar item "Edit" to tell ¬
        menu "Edit" to tell ¬
        menu item "Start Dictation" to ¬
        if exists then click it
```

<sup>*Edited to correct the referencing of the `menu item` chain, as highlighted by [@wch1zpink](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6844169/wch1zpink), which previously prevented it working in *Google Chrome*.*</sup>

Comment: The code under "Alternatively, you can trigger the menu item:", as coded, is interpreted as `exists menu item "Start Dictation" of menu "Edit" of menu bar 1 of process 1 whose frontmost = true` and it will always returns `false` because there is no "Start Dictation" command on the "Edit" menu. It's `Start Dictation…` as you forgot the ellipsis. :)

Comment: @user3439894 Nice to read you again after a while. I believe it only contains the ellipsis when systemwide dictation is deactivated in _System Preferences_.  When activated, the menu item does not contain an ellipsis.  The former (with) is the menu item that allows one to turn on systemwide dictation without entering _System Preferences_.  The latter is the menu item that brings up the dictation input method, which is the one the OP is interested in.  [ **_System info:_** _AppleScript version_: "2.7", _system version_: "10.13.4" ]

Comment: Okay, sounds good... Personally I do not use the built-in Dictation, so it's not turned on in System Preferences, and why it has the ellipsis on my menus and, per your explanation, the code when tested returned `false`. :)

Comment: I'm pretty sure for "Alternatively, you can trigger the menu item:" to work correctly, the mouse cursor needs to be In a field that allows text input,  otherwise, "Start Dictation" command on the "Edit" menu will be grayed out.

Comment: @wch1zpink In such an instance, the `click` action will not do anything, which I imagine would be the desired outcome in most real use situations.  No error is thrown.  In my view, it is demonstrably working correctly, but I am pleased to take on board any suggestions on how you might wish to see it implemented differently.

Answer (score 1):

@CJK really deserves the vote love, as this is only an adjusted extension of his thorough answer...

As taken from @CJK 's solution...

"Alternatively, you can trigger the menu item:"

```
tell application "System Events" to tell ¬
    (the first process whose frontmost is true) to tell ¬
    menu bar 1 to tell ¬
    menu "Edit" to tell ¬
    menu item "Start Dictation" to ¬
    if exists then click it
```

Worked in almtost every application I tested the above code with... It did not work in Google Chrome.

However, this minor adjustment to his original code, Will work in Google Chrome.

```
tell application "System Events" to tell (the first process whose frontmost is true)
    tell menu bar 1 to tell menu bar item "Edit"
        tell menu "Edit"
            try
                click menu item "Start Dictation"
            end try
        end tell
    end tell
end tell
```

**For either of these solutions to actually "Enable Dictation" the mouse cursor must be in a field which allows text input, before the code is run.**

Comment: Now how to end it..."three dots and cancel"....
I want to click on done if dictation is ON using script...
To enable dictation I use:
tell application "System Events" to key code 176